# JavaScript variables declaration that are used in functions

Tags: javascript, variables, memory, declaration

I am new to programming and sorry if a question is dumb.
I am using several functions with variables i, j for looping like - for( j = 0; j < pol.length; j++) ...
Now my lack of knowledge is - I think that declaring "var i = 0..." in every function will creates a memory problem because these functions are used many times and it will declare "i" or "j" each time. So what I do now is I declare var i,j = 0; once outside the functions as a global and then just use them in functions without "var". But I have a feeling - this is terribly wrong.

Another variables that I declare as global "var" are the ones I use later in some functions. For example - var pol_owner = ""; So the code will play with these variables later and change their values. And now I have something like this at the start of my document:

```
var thePol = 0;
var nondrag = 0;
var intGl = 0;
var intMn = 0;
var oldGl = 0;
var oldMn = 0;
var money = 0;
var gifts = 0;
var g_spent = 0;
var the_mess = "";

var j = 0;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var i = 0;
```

And later my functions just use these variables without "var".
I know though the code runs well still I am doing it wrong. Can you give me any advice of how to properly do it. I was looking for some information about it but still I am not sure what is the proper way of doing it.

From the start I was doing my code as: for( var j = 0; j < pol.length; j++) not declaring "j" outside the function, but later I thought that every-time this function run it will declare this var again and again and will not it be more effective to declare it once from the start and later use it without "var". The only problem I see is - creating a global variable that I can accidentally use wrong in some part of the code. But I am kind of controlling this.
So the question basically is - is declaring "var i=0" in every loop part of the function creates any memory problem and should I declare this var once outside the function and use it later without declaration to avoid this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: good practice is not to pollute the global scope, and declare variables in the scope block you need them. Check out this link for some other JS insides http://jstherightway.org/

Comment: don't mind to use local variables, even if a function is a million times called.

Comment: "creates a memory problem because these functions are used many times" — Have you actually profiled memory use before assuming this is a problem and beginning your micro-optimisation?

Comment: Declaring variables public is not wrong way, I want to know that what is / what will be the maximum approx. length of "pol" in your code that matters in iteration rather than memory.

Comment: Javascript will do gc periodically that will release any unreachable memory that allocated previously. After declare multiple times of one variable, the previous one will be release if it is not reachable.

Comment: Thank you guys, now I get it. I will get rid of declaring loop variables outside the function and will put it like - for( var j = 0; j < pol.length; j++) . My "pol" length is about 5000, maximum 10000.